# Python file I/O

Tags: python, io

```
fPath = raw_input('File Path:')
counter = 0;
flag = 0;

with open(fPath) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

for line in content:
    if flag == 0 and line.find("WECS number") or \
    line.find("WECS number") or \
    line.find("WECS name") or \
    line.find("Manufacturer") or \
    line.find("Type") or \
    line.find("Nominal effect") or \
    line.find("Hub height") or \
    line.find("x (local)") or \
    line.find("y (local)") or \
    line.find("x (global)") or \
    line.find("y (global)"):

        if not line.find("y (global)"):
            print ("Alert Last Line!");
        else:
            print("Alert Line!");
```

For some reason, the code seems to be printing "Alert Line!" if a line is just "\n". My intent in creating the "if and or" structure was to ignore all lines not containing the strings listed in the `line.find`'s. Something is going wrong here...

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: this might be better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: One style hint: instead of `content=f.readlines(); for line in content:` just do `for line in f:`.

Answer (score 6):

The string's `.find()` method returns `-1` if the substring is not found. `-1` is nonzero and so is considered true. This probably is not what you expected.

A more Pythonic way (since you don't care about the position of the string) is to use the `in` operator:

```
if "WECS number" in line:   # and so on
```

You can also use `startswith()` and `endswith()` where appropriate:

```
if line.startswith("WECS number"):
```

Finally, you can avoid all those backslashes simply by using parentheses to enclose the entire Boolean expression. If parentheses are open, Python keeps going to the next line.

```
if (condition1 or condition2 or
    condition3 or condition4):
```

Comment: I'd probably write `phrases = ("WECS number", "WECS name")` and then `if any(phrase in line for phrase in phrases)` rather than chain all those `or`s.  If it's really `startswith` that's wanted, that's even better: `line.startswith(phrases)`.

Comment: I have to credit the first answer since both are very good and correct. Thank so much...

Comment: I love that syntax. Now I realize why I'm on Stack Overflow so much.

Comment: @sepoto: be warned that using `in` has one danger which sometimes trips people up: `"cat" in "a catfish is not a feline"` is true, or maybe more to the point `"WECS number" in "WECS number of turtles"` is true.  Whenever you use `in` (or `startswith`, for that matter), be sure you don't have accidental false positives.

Answer (score 1):

The string `find()` method returns -1 if the string is not found.  -1 counts as true in a boolean context.  So your if clauses are executing when you don't think they are.  You'd be better off using `if "blah" in line` to just test whether the substring is present.

Answer (score 1):

`str.find` returns -1 if it doesn't find the substring, and `boolean(-1) == True`, so `line.find("WECS number")` is always True except when the line starts with WECS number, in which case `line.find("WECS name")` is True.

You want:

```
fPath = raw_input('File Path:')

with open(fPath) as f:
  for line in f:
    if any(s in line for s in ("WECS number", "WECS name", "Manufacturer","Type",
                               "Nominal effect", "Hub height", "x (local)",
                               "y (local)", "x (global)", "y (global)",)):

        if "y (global)" in line:
            print("Alert Line!")
        else:
            print ("Alert Last Line!")
```